# Powershell export AD users to csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export, export-to-csv

Im trying to export AD users to a csv file by powershell. Now one field only needs to have the first letter of the value. Eg: name - Kevin, initials - K.

I have tried with substring, but im obviously doing something wrong:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select -Property substring.surname(1,1),surname,givenName,samaccountname,givenN
ame,Mail,Department | Export-CSV "C:\Export\Users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Obviously im still pretty new to powershell.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues here:

1) You're selecting "GivenName" twice - PowerShell won't allow that:
[image]

2) you want substring (0,1) - start as position 0 and count 1 letter along.

3) this should do what you want it to do:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | `
Select @{n='initial';e={$_.surname.substring(0,1)}},surname,givenName,samaccountname,Mail,Department | `
Export-CSV "C:\installs\Users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

essentially, you're creating and recycling a small property array each time - which allows you to set a value (the substring) which is then returned up the chain to the select and then on to your CSV file :)

(might also be worth noting, you're selecting the first letter of the surname, but in your question, you're asking to get K from Kevin - you might want to be selecting from a forename field).

---

Other notes:

`-filter * -properties *` is very computationally expensive - you're getting all fields for all users and only selecting a few.  try listing properties the same way you do in your select.

`select -property` - the -property switch is redundant and optional - just using `Select stuff,otherstuff` will do the same thing and will be easier to read

Comment: I'd argue that encouraging shorthand is not the best advice. `Select-Object -Property` would be complete. This also lends itself to better understanding exactly *what* you're asking PowerShell to do; select a set of properties from the object being fed down the pipeline. Without it, it might be slightly unclear to beginners / people reviewing scripts if/when OP has left the company as it requires knowledge of PowerShell shorthand and optional and default positional parameters. Code being "easier" to read is subjective, but being technically complete is not. Just my 2c, and upvoted anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you feel the process leanthy, you can also try CJWdev tool or Lepide active directory query tool. They both are free and helps to fetch such AD reports quickly.

Comment: This is more a comment then an answer to the question posted above